# onSensorChanged - Is it called only if the sensor reading changes?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I'm developing an application that reads data from many device sensors.

According to documentation:

> [onSensorChanged is] Called when there is a new sensor event. Note that "on changed" is somewhat of a misnomer, as this will also be called if we have a new reading from a sensor with the exact same sensor values (but a newer timestamp).

My question is, if this is true, then why don't I receive any data when there is no sensor change?
For example, if proximity value is 5cm, onSensorChanged will not be called unless proximity value becomes 0 cm.

Same goes for light sensor. According to documentation, it is supposed to keep sending the same light sensor value with newer timestamp. This doesn't happen though. Light sensor will only send data when there is a change on the light.

Comment: You are assuming that the actual sensor hardware sends out an updated reading even when there is no state change in the hardware.

Comment: So if I understood correctly, hardware sensors keep sending values, but onSensorChanged will not be called unless there is a change on these readings?

Comment: That is not what I am saying. You are assuming that sensor hardware continuously sends readings. I am saying that this is not necessarily the case. Think about the light sensor. You are expecting the sensor hardware to keep flooding the OS with readings, even when the light level has not materially changed. That would suck from a power and CPU processing standpoint. It is possible that the hardware only sends the OS readings when they change, and only then can `SensorManager` deliver you a new event. And the behavior of the hardware, and how that ties to `SensorManager`, varies by device.

Comment: That's what I thought too at the beginning. My question is why documentation states otherwise? It clearly says that onSensorChanged will be called "if we have a new reading from a sensor with the exact same sensor values " aka even if light level did not change

Comment: Sensor hardware varies widely. Part of the job of the OS is to "normalize" those readings. Let's look at the light sensor again. The light level is reported to apps in lux. However, *the sensor hardware might not use lux for its unit of measure*. Perhaps for Device X, the light sensor reports millilux (1/1000th of a lux). Android needs to convert that to lux, as that is what apps expect. My interpretation of the docs is that Android just does a straight conversion. So, hardware readings of 999 and 1001 lux both convert to 1 lux, and you get two `SensorEvent` objects with 1 lux.